# Network card not providing maximum throughput Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, intel

I have a server in `OVH`.
My server is able to deliver `1gbps`, I make sure it's actually can deliver this in their rescue mode.
When the system is up to the Ubuntu layer, the performance drops to ~200mbps.

My first thinking is there is a driver issue.
This is my card: `Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GBASE-T`
This is my driver: `driver=i40e driverversion=2.8.20-k`

apparently it quite difficult to understand what is the latest driver for this card through the Intel website :(

I know the latest version of `i40e` is: `https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/i40e%20stable/2.23.17/`, when I check in ubuntu for `apt search i40` the only result is `librte-pmd-i40e20.0/focal-updates 19.11.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 Data Plane Development Kit (librte-pmd-i40e runtime library)` which looks irrelevant.

a. How can I know for sure if `https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/i40e%20stable/2.23.17/` is suitable for my network card? (I can download it, build it, and install it)?

b. How can I troubleshoot the performance issue behind driver update? (I run the `srv_info` tool of Intel and in the insights, I got:

```
Consider manually configuring IRQ CPU affinity for network intensive workloads. System is using the IRQ Balance service to manage IRQ CPU affinity.

Consider setting the Power and Performance policy to 'Performance'. Power and Performance policy is set to 'Normal (6)'.

Consider setting the CPU frequency governors to 'performance'.  CPU frequency governors are set to 'powersave'.
```

Should I follow this? should I run other Intel auto detect tools as well?